# Exercise 2.13, I. Martin Isaacs' Character Theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to solve the exercise 2.13 in Isaacs' Character Theory Book. However I met some difficulties, let me sketch out what I am thinking so that you may tell me a hint.

**The problem 2.13 is stated as follows** : Let $|G'|=p$, a prime. Assume that $G'\subseteq Z(G)$. Show that $\chi(1)^2=|G:Z(G)|$ for every nonlinear $\chi\in Irr(G)$.

**I proceed as follows :** Let $\chi$ be a nonlinear character of $G$. Since $G'\subseteq Z(G)=\cap Z(\chi)$ then $G'\subseteq Z(\chi)$. Therefore $G/Z(\chi)$ is abelian. By THeorem 2.31, we have that 
$$\chi(1)^2=|G:Z(\chi)| $$ 
We would like to prove that $Z(G)=Z(\chi)$. We just need to prove the converse. Assume that $g\in Z(\chi)$, we need to prove that $g\in Z(G)$,i.e., commutes with all $h\in G$. Let $h\in G$, then we need to prove that $[g,h]=1$. Since $[g,h]\in G'\subset Z(\chi)$, then $[g,h]^p=1$ since $|G'|=p$. Moreover, $g\in Z(\chi)$ implies that $[g,h]\in Ker\chi$, and so $\chi([g,h])=\chi(1)>1$, since $\chi$ is nonlinear.

But then, at this stage, I dont know how to proceed to get $[g,h]=1$. Could you give me some hints then.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You assume a lot of notation that isn't necessarily used by everyone who could help you.

Comment: the notation is pretty standard within group/character theory and it is also consistent with the one used by Isaacs in his book.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is obviously the centralizer of $G$, but what is $Z(\chi)$ defined on characters.  And what do you mean "nonlinear"?

Comment: @john: $Z(\chi) = \{ g \in G : |\chi(g)|=\chi(1) \}$. A character $\chi$ is nonlinear iff $\chi(1) > 1$

Comment: @9999: Since $\chi$ is nonlinear, $G'$ is not a subset of the kernel, so $\ker(\chi) \cap G' = 1$ since $G'$ is so small. Hence $[g,h]=1$ as in your argument.

Comment: Thanks alot to @Jack Schmidt. I did not notice about that.

Comment: @JackSchmidt You might consider writing an answer: your comment solved the problem.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: If $G'\subseteq \ker\chi$, then $G/\ker\chi$ is abelian so it has only linear characters, so $\chi$ is linear, a contradiction, right? Why is $[g,h]\in \ker\chi$?

Comment: @LeonLampret: the original question proves $[g,h] \in \ker(\chi)$: it is just because $g \in Z(\chi)$. If $X$ is the associated rep, then $X(g)$ is a scalar matrix, so $X([g,h]) = [ X(g), X(h) ] = 1$, so $[g,h] \in \ker(\chi)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $\chi$ is nonlinear, $G'$ is not a subset of the kernel, so $\ker(\chi) \cap G' = 1$ since $|G'|=p$ is so small. Hence $[g,h]=1$ and your argument is complete.